# How do I configure SSL on Apache on Ubuntu?

Tags: apache, ubuntu-12.04

I tried to enable SSL on my Apache server on Ubuntu, but when I restart the Apache server it shows the following error:

> Syntax error on line 3 of /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default:
>   Invalid command 'RewriteEngine', perhaps misspelled or defined by a module not included in the server configuration
>   Action 'configtest' failed.

Answer (score 2):

That is complaining about mod_rewrite not your ssl cert.

Try

```
sudo a2enmod rewrite
sudo service apache2 restart
```